# Verbments file *.pyg.vrb not found

Tags: miktex, verbments

I am using Verbments package in texworks from MiKeTeX and I have added -shell-escape to the argument list but I keep getting this error

```
! LaTeX Error: File `untitled-2.pyg.vrb' not found.
```

here is my code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{verbments}


\begin{document}

Test
\begin{pyglist}[language=c] 
                for(int i=0;i<32;i=i+2)
                {
                    x[i]=a[i]*c[i];
                    x[i+1]=a[i+1]*c[i+1];
                }
                \end{pyglist}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you have `pygmentize` installed?

Comment: yes I have installed it but i am still getting the same error

Comment: Just encountered this error myself. I was able to resolve it by not using a separate output directory, i.e. having all generated files next to the .tex file.